# Как поворачивать картинку по оси при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: c#, wpf

Образно говоря, есть изображение танка, который может двигаться в любые стороны с помощью кнопок-стрелок на клавиатуре + картинка танка не вылезает за края (у края останавливается) но при этом мне надо чтобы сама картинка поворачивалась не то получается что я еду наверх боком.

ниже код как он едет и останавливается перед окном (не идеально но в моем варианте работает как надо)

```
private void KeyDowdDo(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Key == Key.Left)

            if (image.Margin.Left > 10)
                image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left - 15,image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);
            else
                image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);

        if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            if (image.Margin.Left < 1330)
                image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left + 15, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);
            else image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);

        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
            if (image.Margin.Top > 10)
                image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top - 15, 0, 0);
            else
                image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);

        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            if (image.Margin.Top < 760)
                image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top + 15, 0, 0);
            else
                image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Image Source="ttt.jpg" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
  <Image.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
      <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </TransformGroup>
  </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Аналогично и в коде

```
  System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup tg;
  System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform rt;
  tg = image.RenderTransform as System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup;
  if (tg == null)
  {
    tg = new System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup();
    image.RenderTransform = tg;
  }
  rt = tg.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x is System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform) as System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform;
  if (rt == null)
  {
    rt = new System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform();
    tg.Children.Add(rt);
  }
  rt.Angle = 90;
```

можно упростить, запомнив `System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform rt;`

```
  System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform rt = new System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform();
  System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup tg = new System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup();
  tg.Children.Add(rt);
  image.RenderTransform = tg;
  .....
  rt.Angle = 90;
```

и не искать его более в `image.RenderTransform`

не забудьте указать `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"` в `Image`

Comment: Ну так Вы покажите человеку как в коде, сразу, он же не XAML просил

Comment: Ответ дополнил. Думаю человек и сам мог бы догадаться до этого. Всё же на виду.

Comment: а модно пример из кода C#?

Comment: А можно пример из кода C#

Comment: Я только на нем и разбираюсь пока что  (что вы ожидали от меня, 14 летнего подростка)